# Continuity of $\log(xyz)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have problems in understanding this exercise: be $f(x, y, z)$ such that
$$f(x, y, z) = \begin{cases} \log(xyz) & xyz > 0 \\ a & xyz \leq 0\end{cases}$$

For which $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ the function is continuous and why?

*Attempts*

So I thought to restrict it at $y = mx$ and $z = nx$ getting

$$f(x, mx, nx) = \log(mnx^3) = A + 3\log(x)$$

which holds when $x > 0$ (assuming $m, n$ both positive).
$A$ stands for $3\log(m) + 3\log(n)$.
Yet at this point the only way for the function to be continuous is that the limits in zero are equal. But it's impossible since $\log(0^+) \to -\infty$ and $a$ is a real number.

Yet I suspect I am wrong somehow. Any help?

Comment: It might be easier to first consider the function $g(t) = \begin{cases} \log t, & t>0 \\ a,& t < 0\end{cases}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Smooth. But again I cannot think of that function to be continuous for any reason... Am I missing something, or it was easier than I thought?

Comment: What is the domain of the function? The question is a little vague. Note that $g$ above is continuous in the domain $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @copper.hat It's not specified

Comment: @copper.hat I mean, for how the question is posed, I would guess the function is continuous... for all $x, y, z$ such that $xyz > 0$ and $xyz < 0$ but not at zero (??)

Comment: If the domain is $D=\{ (x,y,z) \mid xyz \neq 0 \}$ then $f$ is continuous. If you pick some $(x',y',z')$ then for any $\epsilon >0$ you can find a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x,y,z)-f(x',y',z')| < \epsilon$ whenever $|(x,y,z)-(x',y',z')| < \delta$. There are basically two cases to consider.

Comment: @copper.hat We are not allowed to reason in terms of $\epsilon-\delta$ to study continuity...

Comment: @copper.hat I just noticed that the function is defined as $a$ if $xyz \color{red}{\leq} 0$. THis changes things...